# Grid portfolio with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I just wondering how can i do this type of grid portfolio, with this nice effect.
The effect triggered when the tab change.

> http://adammunns.com/grid-portfolio/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add an overlay div that will cover your image (with opacity). Now register a on hover event in jquery that on over will animate height to 100% (on out back to 0).

```
img.hover(function() {
  overlay.animate('height', '100%');
}, function() {
  overlay.animate('height', 0);
});
```

Of course catch for animation in progress (stop current) so that it dont loop when you hover quickly few times.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't want the mouseover effect. What I want is the effect thats is triggered when the tab change. My bad.

Comment: ah, ill answer tomorrow then :p

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but the following seems to be the relevant jQuery from your example site:

```
// filter items when filter link is clicked
var selectors = [];

$j('#filters a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selector = $j(this).attr('data-filter');

    $j('#filters li').removeClass('active');
    $j(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
});

var box = $j('.pboxgraphic');
var hover = 'span.hover,span.hover_solid,.pboxtext';

if( $j('#projects').hasClass('fade') ) {
    box.mouseenter(function(el) {
        $j(this).find(hover).stop().fadeIn("fast");                             
    });

    box.mouseleave(function(el) {
        $j(this).find(hover).stop().fadeOut("fast");                                                                
    });
} else {
    box.mouseenter(function(el) {
        $j(this).find(hover).stop().slideToggle("fast");                                
    });

    box.mouseleave(function(el) {
        $j(this).find(hover).stop().slideToggle("fast");                                                                
    });
}
```